# Meaning of hadoop job status

Tags: hadoop

I run the command `hadoop job -list all` to show all the submitted jobs, and it shows state meaning as:  Running : 1     Succeded : 2    Failed : 3      Prep : 4.

But now I have a job whose status is 5. The `list` command output like this: `job_201209101415_429766 5       1358332807055   user   NORMAL  NA`

Anybody konws what it means?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job status 5 implies Killed. Please check this web link

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/api/constant-values.html#org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobStatus.KILLED

Comment: These links are broken